# Is manual check of "alg" required when validation JWT?

Tags: .net, jwt

I have to validate a jwt access token. (in a legacy WCF REST Service .NET 4.7.2)
To do that I use the nuget package [Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens/) 6.7.1. An example from okta demonstrates how to do this ([example](https://developer.okta.com/code/dotnet/jwt-validation/)). (To which i am very thankful)

After using the library to validate the token they write:

> You also must verify that the alg claim matches the expected algorithm which was used to sign the token. You'll have to perform this check after the ValidateToken method returns a validated token:

```
// Validate alg
var validatedToken = await ValidateToken(idToken, issuer, configurationManager);
var expectedAlg = SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256; //Okta uses RS256

if (validatedToken.Header?.Alg == null || validatedToken.Header?.Alg != expectedAlg)
{
    throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("The alg must be RS256.");
}
```

As well there is a [blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/) from Auth0 about vulnerabilities in libraries "trusting" the "alg" value of jwt header.

When I check the [validation implementation](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens/JsonWebTokenHandler.cs) of the IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens package i think the IsSupportedAlgorithm call in the following code protects the library from using a false key/alg combination.

```
internal static bool ValidateSignature(byte[] encodedBytes, byte[] signature, SecurityKey key, string algorithm, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
{
    var cryptoProviderFactory = validationParameters.CryptoProviderFactory ?? key.CryptoProviderFactory;
    if (!cryptoProviderFactory.IsSupportedAlgorithm(algorithm, key))
    {
        LogHelper.LogInformation(LogMessages.IDX14000, algorithm, key);
        return false;
    }
```

Therefore i think the okta JWT Validation Guide is wrong or outdated in that aspect. Would you agree with me?

---

Answer (score 0):

Okta's jwt validation guide specifically mentions:
"You'll have to perform this check (alg check) after the ValidateToken method returns a validated token"

I believe it is a problem only if the validating library relied on this alg claim to pick the verification algorithm.

Comment: I think so too. That's all what's the question about. They write you should check, but use a library where the check does not seem to be necessary for me. The thing is I do not want to limit the alg to Rs256 when the oidc discovery document publishes the key / alg pair in the jwks parameter.